# PHP show one decimal place issue

Tags: php, decimal

I'm trying to show one decimal place for rating number I have

but it returns unexpected value.

I used `number_format`  and the round functions  and both have the same issue, or i'm doing something wrong.

I tried to make this number show one decimal number

4.96    and it always returns  5   instead of 4.9

```
    number_format(4.96, 1)

    round(4.96, 1) 

    round(4.96, 1,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
```

both functions returns 5 instead of 4.9

I searched all answers but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: `4.96` is closer to `5.00` than it is to `4.90`, so the rounding is doing what it's told to - rounding to the nearest 1-decimal place, `5.0`.

Comment: but mathematically speaking, 4.96, to 1dp is 5.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? you want 1 decimal ? you want to round the second decimal?

Answer (score 1):

Rounding 4.96 will round .9 up, so it will be 5 in all cases. If you want to do it without rounding, you may have to tweak it a bit to fool it:

```
floor(4.96 * 10) / 10;  // 4.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function you can use to achieve this.

```
function convertToSingleDecimal($num, $precision = 2) {
return floor($num) . substr(str_replace(floor($num), '', $num), 0, $precision + 1);
}
  print convertToSingleDecimal("4.96", 1);
```